# Extending jQuery's className selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I override `$(".className")` such that

`if(className="xyz") then alert("Hello")`

and then do what JQuery is doing.

Comment: so you want to automatically post an `alert` whenever a selector is used?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Check if elements with that class exist? If you are trying to do what adam thinks: Don't do that. It is most likely a bad thing.

Comment: @adam : thats just an example.I may want to do something more in the future.For now , i want to know if that is possible and if yes , how.

@ThiefMaster : No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to override/extend the method in jQuery that finds nodes. I can't find any hooks and/or listeners that can be attached to that functionality in the code, so I guess you'll have to modify the source code if you want to achieve this functionality.

I'd suggest adding some sort of event listener interface so you can attach this to arbitrary selectors that fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks , could you give me an example for adding the event listener and attaching it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if($('#selector').hasClass('classname')) alert('Hello')
```

Comment: I dont want to do it this way. I need to extend the class selector.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
if ($('div[class="xyz"]').length) {
  alert('Hello');
}
```